# Windows OSes and Memory Management-- What happens when an application is minimized?

Tags: .net, windows, com, windows-7, windows-xp

I'm asking this question for posterity reasons and general interest.  Years ago I noticed an odd behavior within Windows.  I know this works in XP and at that time it also worked in Windows 2000 and even 98 and I'd assume this behavior still works for Windows 7.

To setup my question, try this experiment by following these steps.

1. Open the Task Manager and navigate to the Processes tab.
2. Open an application that you use that you know consumes a fair amount of memory (a web browser should work fine) and find the process in the Task Manager.
3. Now use the application by opening windows, documents, web pages, etc. until the Memory Usage of your application grows significantly.
4. Make note of the applications Memory Usage and minimize the application-- you should see a significant reduction in the amount of memory that the application is using.
5. Finally, restore the application.

After restoring the Window, you should that that the Memory Usage of the application should spike a little but no where near as much as it was before you minimized the application.  This is quite consistent with any GUI based application but it is certainly more profound with larger applications.

**QUESTION**

Internally within the OS, what process is taking place that forces this (assumed) garbage collection to take place?  Furthermore, via COM or some .Net calls is there a way to force this process without minimizing an application?  If so, please provide source code.  The language doesn't matter.

If you are like me, you may keep a lot of applications open at the same time.  Memory usage can creep up... up... up.. and before you know it, you need to close a few applications to free resources.  It would be nice if I could at least integrate into the software that I have control a mechanism to force garbage collection from the OS similar to the behavior from the exercise above.

I know that in .Net there is a GC object and you can call the garbage clean-up as you desire.  It does not, however, seem to be related with the nature of the memory clean-up that happens when an application is minimized.

I hope this is a head scratcher and that after years of curiosity that someone- can give me a good, technical explanation of what is going on.

**Page Files and Going Further Down the "Rabbit Hole"**

Interesting stuff has been posted as an answer to this question by Kragen & Alex K.  Upon reading the [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=293215#appliesto) they both posted, I see that there is also a way to prevent this behavior from happening.  What are some examples of when you would want to prevent this paging freeing from taking place?  I'm trying to read through the documentation to learn as much about this as I can.  A lot of this information is new to me because I've never needed to implement any of this within .Net applications.  Considering a use-case would help me grasp the reasoning of why and when I would want to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Most applications (I know Firefox) will take time to clean up when the window is minimized because it won't interfere with the user. What applications have you tried this with? Are you sure it's an OS level thing?

Comment: The term "memory usage" is not very precise. Do you mean working set, size of virtual address space, private bytes, or what?

Comment: @Earlz-- this seems to be very consistent with every application (MS Word, Access, Excel, Web Browsers, Design Environments, etc.) so I would assume that this is happening via Windows system calls that the kernel fires when an application is minimized.

Comment: @John Saunders-- I'm not really sure how to answer your question.  The best I can say is "something" is happening consistently, for practically every GUI based application, when it is minimized.  You can see the "Memory Usage" decreases every time you minimize an application that has been open and in use for at least a few minutes.  Some times the usage drop is only a small percentage, some times it's quite drastic.  However, I've never seen the Memory Usage spike back up to the full amount before the initial minimization.

Comment: @RLH: if you mean "Memory Usage" as displayed by Task Manager, then maybe it's only Task Manager that is changing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process you are seeing is **not** garbage collection - Windows is "trimming the working set" (i.e. paging as much memory as it can to disk) in order to free up memory for foreground applications.

See the following links for more information:

- [The working set of an application is trimmed when its top-level window is minimized (KB)](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=293215)
- [SetProcessWorkingSetSize Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234)

The KB article linked above describes both how you can prevent this from automatically happening (by intercepting the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` command), and how you can explicitly cause this to happen at any time (by calling `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`).

Comment: Excellent!  Problem solved in under 30 minutes!  I <3 SO!! The last time I tried to research this behavior (which was probably 5 years or so ago) I couldn't find an answer, any where.  This information is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Minimizing a window can cause windows to [trim the working set](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293215) of that process for the benefit of the remaining foreground applications (accomplished by calling  [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234.aspx)).